# How to run sshd on port 500 in High Sierra?

Tags: command-line, ssh, high-sierra

They changed things in later versions of macOS so that you can't just edit `etc/ssh/sshd_config` like you would in Linux.  What do I type into the shell to run sshd on port 500 instead of 22?

Comment: Any of this solutions working? https://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x

Comment: is there any way to just like "symlink" the port -- pipe everything straight through for a test -- rather than loading up a .plist etc ?

Answer (score 2):

To modify the ssh port, you have to edit the ssh launch daemon of the ssh server host:

- [disable SIP](https://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html)
- open ssh.plist:

  ```
  sudo nano /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
  ```
- modify the `<key>Sockets</key>` (example port here: 10022) from

  ```
      ...
      <key>Sockets</key>
      <dict>
              <key>Listeners</key>
              <dict>
                      <key>SockServiceName</key>
                      <string>ssh</string>
                      <key>Bonjour</key>
                      <array>
                              <string>ssh</string>
                              <string>sftp-ssh</string>
                      </array>
              </dict>
      </dict>
      ...
  ```

  to

  ```
      ...
      <key>Sockets</key>
      <dict>
              <key>Listeners</key>
              <dict>
                      <key>SockServiceName</key>
                      <string>10022</string>
                      <key>Bonjour</key>
                      <array>
                              <string>10022</string>
                              <string>10022</string>
                      </array>
              </dict>
      </dict>
      ...
  ```
- unload and load the daemon

  ```
  sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist 
  sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
  ```
- test the ssh daemon
- [enable SIP](https://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html)

---

An alternative, less intrusive approach is to create a second *ssh* launch daemon in /Library/LaunchDaemons/:

- copy the ssh.plist

  ```
  sudo cp /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist
  ```
- modify the ssh2.plist:

  ```
  sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist
  ```

  change the key *Label* to

  ```
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.openssh.sshd2</string>
  ```

  change the key `<key>Sockets</key>` as described earlier
- disable SSH in the System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Login
- load the launch daemon:

  ```
  sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist
  ```
- with strict key checking enabled in the ssh config file on a ssh client host you may have to remove the ssh server from the known_hosts file of this remote host.
- access the ssh server with `ssh user@IP -p <port>`

Comment: oh brother..... thats why i stayed on 10.12 until last week. i knew once Apple removed the 3.5mm jack it would be all over what a pity.